# Defy gravity torques with gyroscopes?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, rigid-body-dynamics, gyroscopes

**Context**

On the following drawing, a platform is hung from the ceiling not exactly from its centre of gravity. Because of this it can't sustain an arbitrary orientation for long; I want to increase its stiffness with the use of 3 orthogonal fast spinning flywheels, but before building those flywheels I need to know how big they need to be by making a dynamic model...
[image]

... And I have been unable to model the gyroscopic effect [Edit: end removed for clarity].

**Question**

How can I model the 3 flywheels reaction to (themselves and) the gravity torque, be it through a rate increment or a torque (to inject in the plant model)?

---

**Implementing Lelesquiz's answer**

### Top level equations: Euler-Lagrange

The goal is to solve for each timestep for the angles $(\phi, \theta, \psi)$ using the equations, in inertial frame:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\phi}}\right)-\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi}= (\boldsymbol{M_g}-\sum_{k=1}^3 \boldsymbol{M_{wk}})\cdot \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{\omega_b}}{\partial \dot{\phi}}$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}}\right)-\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta}= (\boldsymbol{M_g}-\sum_{k=1}^3 \boldsymbol{M_{wk}})\cdot \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{\omega_b}}{\partial \dot{\theta}}$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\psi}}\right)-\frac{\partial L}{\partial \psi}= (\boldsymbol{M_g}-\sum_{k=1}^3 \boldsymbol{M_{wk}})\cdot \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{\omega_b}}{\partial \dot{\psi}}$$
Where $M_g$ is the gravity torque, $M_{wk}$ is the motor torque applied on the flywheel k (opposite of what's applied on the platform), and $\omega_b$ is the platform rate vector in inertial frame. 3 other equations based on $\alpha_k$, the angles of the flywheels, should have been added to completely characterize the system but the rates of the wheels are inputs, measured directly. The torques on the wheels are inputs as well (and the command of the closed loop system).

Knowing that the lagrangian $L=T-U$ in the inertial frame.

### Kinetic energy T

$$ T(\phi, \theta, \psi, \dot{\phi},  \dot{\theta}, \dot{\psi}) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^3
  \left(\boldsymbol{N_{k,Ri}^T}\boldsymbol{[I_{wO,Ri}]}\boldsymbol{N_{k,Ri}} \right) + \frac{1}{2} \left( m_{b} \boldsymbol{v_{b,Ri}}^T\boldsymbol{v_{b,Ri}}+\boldsymbol{\omega_{b,Ri}^T} \boldsymbol{[I_{bG,Ri}]}  \boldsymbol{\omega_{b,Ri}} \right)$$
  Where $m_b$ is the mass of the system (with wheels on), $\boldsymbol{v_{b}}$ the velocity vector of the center of gravity of the system, $\boldsymbol{\omega_{b}}$ the system's rate vector (wheels not spinning) and $\boldsymbol{[I_{bG}]}$ the inertia matrix of the system about its center of gravity (which needs to be transported from the guimbal centre 0), $[I_{wO}]$ the inertia matrix of the flywheels about their axis, and $\boldsymbol{N_{k}}$ the rate vector of the flywheels in the inertial frame. 
$$\begin{array}{lc}\boldsymbol{[I_{wO,Ri}]}=\boldsymbol{[R_{ib}]}\left[\begin{matrix}J_w & 0 & 0\\ 0 & J_w &0\\0 & 0& J_w\end{matrix}\right] \boldsymbol{[R_{bi}]} 
                  \end{array}$$
  $$\boldsymbol{v_{b}}=\boldsymbol{\omega_{b,Ri}}\times\boldsymbol{\Delta_{b,Ri}}$$
  $$\begin{array}{lc}
\boldsymbol{[I_{bG,Ri}]}= \boldsymbol{[R_{ib}]}\boldsymbol{[I_{bO,Rb}]}\boldsymbol{[R_{bi}]}+m_b& \left(\begin{matrix}
                    \Delta_{by,Ri}^2+\Delta_{bz,Ri}^2 & -\Delta_{bx,Ri}\Delta_{by,Ri} & -\Delta_{bx,Ri}\Delta_{bz,Ri} \\
                    -\Delta_{bx,Ri}\Delta_{by,Ri} & \Delta_{bx,Ri}^2+\Delta_{bz,Ri}^2 & -\Delta_{by,Ri}\Delta_{bz,Ri} \\
                    -\Delta_{bx,Ri}\Delta_{bz,Ri} & -\Delta_{by,Ri}\Delta_{bz,Ri} & \Delta_{bx,Ri}^2+\Delta_{by,Ri}^2
                  \end{matrix}\right)  
                  \end{array}$$
 $\boldsymbol{\Delta_{b,Ri}}$ being the guimbal centre - center of gravity vector of the system expressed in the inertial frame. See below "Euler angle expressions" for the transformation body-inertial $\boldsymbol{<vector>_i}=\boldsymbol{[R_{ib}]}\boldsymbol{<vector>_b}$.

### Potential energy U

$$U(\phi, \theta, \psi) = -m\boldsymbol{g_{Ri}}.\boldsymbol{\Delta_{b,Ri}}$$
 The minus sign comes from the fact U is minimum with the guimbal-CG vector pointing downward (dot product positive).

### Euler angles expressions

The Euler angles 313 have been selected as a coordinate system, which gives the rotation matrix from inertial frame $(0 \boldsymbol{X_i Y_i Z_i})$ to body frame $(0 \boldsymbol{X_b Y_b Z_b})$:
$$  \begin{array}{lc}
\boldsymbol{R_{RbRi}}(\phi, \theta, \psi)= & \left[\begin{matrix}
                    cos \psi & sin \psi & 0 \\
                    -sin \psi & cos \psi & 0 \\
                    0 & 0 & 1
                  \end{matrix}\right] \left[\begin{matrix}
                                      1 & 0 & 0 \\
                                      0 & cos \theta & sin \theta \\
                                      0 & -sin \theta & cos \theta
                                    \end{matrix}\right] \left[\begin{matrix}
                                                        cos \phi & sin \phi & 0 \\
                                                        -sin \phi & cos \phi & 0 \\
                                                        0 & 0 & 1
                                                      \end{matrix}\right] 
                  \end{array}$$
The rate vector is obtained by summing the projections on each axis of the inertial frame the $\boldsymbol{\dot{\phi},\dot{\theta},\dot{\psi}}$ vectors): 
$$\begin{array}{lc} \boldsymbol{w_{b,Ri}}= & \left[\begin{matrix}
  \dot{\theta}cos\phi+\dot{\psi} sin\theta sin\phi \\
        \dot{\theta}sin\phi+\dot{\psi} sin\theta cos\phi \\
        \dot{\phi}+\dot{\psi}cos\theta
                                                      \end{matrix}\right]\end{array}$$

### Problem

The kinetic energy of the wheels is independent on the Euler angles, so the rates of the wheels have no effect, which is wrong! Since it's absolutely normal that no matter the rotation matrix the norm of the wheels rates vector does not change, the kinetic energy expression or even the top level equations must be wrong.

Comment: Could you explain the expression $\mathbf \omega_p = I^{-1} \int^t_0 (\mathbf{\tau_1}+\mathbf{\tau_2}+\mathbf{\tau_3}+\mathbf{\tau_g}) dt$? What is the role of $I^{-1}$, which I take to be the inverse of the inertia tensor of the platform? What is precisely the meaning of $\text{angles} = \int_0^t \mathbf{\omega_p} dt$?

Comment: How did you get the left sides of your first set of equations $$\mathbf{\tau_2} + \mathbf{\tau_3} +\mathbf{\tau_g} \\ \vdots \qquad \qquad \qquad ?$$

Comment: I'm only simulating the plant, which from given torques at each timestep integrates them affected by the inverse of the platform inertia to give the angular rates of the platform, and then integrates the latter to give the angles of the platform in the inertial frame. I've updated my post with more details. The left side of the equations for the gyroscopes are the external torques as seen from each of the wheels: the other wheels' and the gravity's.

Comment: What is keeping the platform from spinning about the rope?

Comment: The combination of all the wheels - they're supposed to stabilise each of the 3 angles.

Comment: Have you included the gravity forces in the total torque about the center of mass?

Comment: Your system is not trivial. I would begin by simplifying the system by considering only one gyroscope. Take the platform to be a massless rigid rod, fixed at one end and with a massive particle some way along it; then place a freely rotating ring at the end of the rod (orientation up to you, but keep it simple). Your next job is to parametrize this system: assign a set of variables that uniquely determine every position this system can take. Then calculate `T` and `V`. Try to solve this system first, then you can start worrying about making it more complicated.

Comment: By the way, like I said, this is not a trivial problem. Go slowly. For one thing, don't simply take Lelesquiz's equation, because for one thing there should be 5 variables involved: one angle for every gyroscope and two angles for the orientation of the platform. And also be aware that `L=T-V`, not the sum of `T` and `V`.

Comment: @Zorawar, thanks. The thing is 3 of them makes me do 3 times the same thing, it's just that I can't get started on one. For one thing, I don't get how the orientation of the platform can be uniquely specified with only 2 angles (it's not a vector but a set of vectors).

Comment: @MisterMystère: model the platform as a massive particle at the point GC on your diagram. Connect this particle with a massless rod to the fixed point at which the rope connects to the platform. This is now an effective model for the platform because the motion of the COM encodes the motion of the whole extended platform. In other words, simplify the set of vectors that is the platform with only one vector to the the COM. Unless you want to consider that the rope itself can swing, we can take the rope to be motionless, and so the COM vector can be orientated in only two directions.

Comment: I'm not worried about the platform, more about the gyroscopes on it: with only two angles I can't account for the roll around the massless "rod".

Comment: @MisterMystère: OK, but the particle is dimensionless, so the angle for the roll around the rod doesn't describe a mechanically distinct state. At least for the single gyroscope system. But, you're correct when we consider the 3-gyroscope system, we'll need the third angle then. My mistake, in that case we'll need six variables, unless I've made a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Since in my last post I made a lot of mistakes, I'll try to improve that answer starting from scratch.

First of all: lagrangian coordinates.
It first seemed clear that two coordinates suffice in describing the body orientation. Of course this is false, since in order to describe every possible orientation one needs three coordinates. We'll call them $(\theta, \phi, \psi)$.

Any more coordinates? I don't think so. The only external forces acting of the body are the rope tension and gravity. They are both directed along the vertical, so no oscillations should develop.

Next: rotation description. Refer to [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_body_dynamics). You could pick Euler angles or Tait-Bryan, your choice. Given the angles, you then compute the rotation matrix. With the matrix you can compute any vector rotation regarding the body. Will call this $R(\theta (t), \phi (t), \psi (t)) = R(t)$.

Body description: your model depends on many quantities. They essentially are

- Initial body orientation and initial angular velocity
- Initial relative positions of the three gyroscopes
- Initial orientations of the gyroscopes and angular velocities
- Initial center of gravity position
- $\theta(t), \phi(t), \psi(t)$

Given any of these vectors $\vec{x}_0$, you can compute the corresponding vector at time $t$ as $\vec{x}(t) = R(t) \cdot \vec{x}_0 = R(\theta, \phi, \psi) \cdot \vec{x}_0 = \vec{x}(\theta, \phi, \psi)$.

What's next? Compute the kinetic energy of the body. It is given by

$$ T(\theta, \phi, \psi, \dot{\theta}, \dot{\phi}, \dot{\psi}) = \frac{1}{2} I_1 \omega_1^2(\theta, \phi, \psi) + \frac{1}{2} I_2 \omega_2^2(\theta, \phi, \psi) +\frac{1}{2} I_3 \omega_3^2(\theta, \phi, \psi) + \frac{1}{2} I_{TOT} \omega_{body}^2(\theta, \phi, \psi, \dot{\theta}, \dot{\phi}, \dot{\psi}) $$.

Again note that the gyroscopes' angular velocities are constant in magnitude (if you admin no friction and only forces normal to the axis, but they rotate with the body: their relative angle to the body has remain fixed.

Finally compute the potential energy as
$$ U(\theta, \phi, \psi) = mgh(\theta, \phi, \psi)$$

The total lagrangian is

$L = T-U$.

Now you should be able to apply the Euler Lagrange equations and solve numerically. Good luck! You might need to help yourself with mathematica or any other sort of algebra package in order not to damage your brain with the derivatives and scalar products.

Comment: The three angles $\theta, \phi, \psi$ describe the state of the body, but you'll also need angles $\alpha_i$ for the orientations of the discs of the gyroscope $i$ wrt to the body as well won't you? The gyroscopes rotate freely from the body.

Comment: Don't do they rotate with constant angular speed?

Comment: Thanks for the improved answer, I'll read that with a clear head tomorrow. I'm granting you the +50 in the meantime, I may set another to close the case! To answer your question, for now they rotate at constant speed but as soon as it's done they'll be controlled so variable speed. At least their axes are the same as those of the platform.

Comment: @Lelesquiz: sure, but what is that (constant) angular velocity? Its not simply $\dot\theta$, $\dot\phi,$ or $\dot\psi$ since they are the motions of the platform. The platform may be motionless and the gyroscopes will still rotate, so you will necessary need another coordinate. Remember that the coordinates specify a state of the system. If you have only $\theta, \phi, \psi$ you can't distinguish the positions of the gyroscope as it rotates.

Comment: If the rate is constant, we just have to transform $\omega$'s, an another coordinate is necessary only when they change right? @Lelesquiz: my second question is still on, i.e. am I solving for $\omega_{body}$ (can't see anything else)? If so should I inject it in my plant as an increment? Because I don't see how the gravitational torque is accounted for in that model: mgh is not dependent on the lever arm and it does not change with the angles does it?

Comment: Yep, in case of constant rotation rate you don't need any other variable. Anyway, you are not directly solving for $\omega_{body}$, you need to solve for $\theta (t), \phi (t), \psi (t)$ and only later you can substitute that into $\omega_{body}(t)$ since you know how it depends on $\theta (t), \phi (t), \psi (t)$. And mgh is indeed dependent on the lever arm! h  is the z component of the arm vector, and since the arm vector rotates with the body, it changes with time!

Comment: You need to write down the total kinetic energy of the system. Therefore, even if the angular velocity of the gyroscope is constant, you still need to state what its kinetic energy is. Write down the total kinetic energy of the system and you will necessarily see that you need more than just $(\theta, \phi, \psi)$

Comment: @Zorawar you will need $\omega_1$, $\omega_2$, $\omega_3$, but since they will be constant, why would you include them? It's more simple to just account for their rotation, isn't it?

Comment: @Lelesquiz: you mean if you put them into L and then only take E-L eqns in $(\theta, \phi, \psi)$ they will drop out anyway, so why use them in the first place? Ah, that would be the wrong way to do it, surely. Otherwise the EOM would be no different to if the gyroscopes weren't there in the first place, which is clearly incorrect. I would suggest that from an arbitrary starting position the motion of the platform would affect the angular velocity of the gyroscopes until the system found its equilibrium point and then the gyros' angular velocity would stay approx. constant.

Comment: @Lelesquiz: ...but I'm not sure about that without solving the equations first; having never solved a complicated gyroscopic system besides the basic symmetric and asymmetric tops that everyone solves in their undergrad course, I can't predict what they would do. I am wary about making assumptions. I would take the system to be very general and then see what result I get from it. It's an interesting problem and if I get time I'll try to write the system's Lagrangian myself.

Comment: @Zorawar: I don't agree. "I would suggest that from an arbitrary starting position the motion of the platform would affect the angular velocity of the gyroscopes until the system found its equilibrium point and then the gyros' angular velocity would stay approx. constant." The forces acting on the gyros are only perpendicular to the rotation direction. Then the virtual work done by this forces would be zero in ANY case. That's why you would get constant rotation speed.

Comment: @Lelesquiz: Even if we disregard the general position of the platform, clearly the gravitational torque cannot be perpendicular to the angular momenta of all the three gyroscopes since they have been drawn to form a basis of 3-space. Thus the torque will change the angular speed of at least one of the gyroscopes at all times.

Comment: Nope again, gravitational force/torque will not change the magnitude of the angular momentum, just the direction. The gyroscope constraint is clearly non dissipative and acts perpendicular to the angular momentum. Try that in a simple experiment and you'll see it's quite obvious!

Comment: Hi again, I have updated my above answer with the progress I've made after reading your comments. Could you both give it a look? I have the feeling I'm not doing right the extension to variable speed gyroscopes. Thanks for your help, I'll give another +50 when the case is nearing closure (or more depending on what's left to do).

Comment: Hold on, stop and reflect. Try to distinguish clearly between the case of constant and variable angular gyroscopes' speed. In case constant speed the system is described by that lagrangian and those Euler-Lagrange equations (just the first three of them, not the last three).

Comment: In case of variable speed it is quite different: since the system itself cannot change the gyros' speed, something "external" is driving them. That is, the electric motors that control them add or subtract kinetic energy from the system. Then you have to change the Euler-Lagrange equations in order to account for the external virtual works. See i.e. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_work, especially  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_work#Couples and  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_work#Virtual_work_and_rigid_body_dynamics

Comment: @Lelesquiz: it's possible we're not talking about the same system. A general spinning object may have its angular speed changed by a torque, but it depends on the system under consideration (cf. the symmetrical top). It also depends on whether to rotation is wrt to a reference system in motion with the body or one that is "fixed". In such a system the freely rotating disc does not change angular speed to the latter but does with the former. We should not continue without drawing a picture and clearly defining the system first.

Comment: @MisterMystère: Before anything else I would draw a "proper" picture first describing the system in more detail. And I would start with a simpler system and build up to the complicated one. And note that your flywheels will have to be much larger than the mass of the platform in order to be effective. This will affect the centre of mass of your system, so the placement of the flywheels needs to be considered before you start any calculations.

Comment: I've updated my post with what I understand is what should be done when the rates of the wheels are variable. Is it right or is there anything I'm missing, before I (and someone else who's giving me a hand) plunge into the equations? Thanks for your help. I'll add the angles on my drawing.

Comment: In the first three equations the final $\delta \phi$, $\delta \theta$ and $\delta \psi$ look suspect to me. How did you get it? What is $\delta \phi$ supposed to mean?

Comment: Spot on, I thought virtual work was the right term but it's generalised forces instead. Does it look good otherwise (updated)?

Comment: Now you might be onto something...Just be sure to put the right expression of $\omega_i$, $i=1,2,3$ as function of $\psi, \phi, \theta, \alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$. Also check that minus sign in front of U$. Then I would personally test the simulation starting with the simplest case (everything stopped, with the system in the barycenter), going to more and more complicated situations.

Comment: Creating the algebric loops we noticed that the three last equations were only modelling how the wheel rates change, but that parameter is measured on the field (input of the block). However the three first equations did not account for the external wheels torques, so I've updated my post with the equations we're doing now.

Comment: Cool, keep up with the hard work!